# Generate an alphanumeric code from a number in php

Tags: php, math

I want to asing an 5 letters alphanumeric code to all the user that I have in my database, at the momment the only way to identify my user is by their username or ID field in the MySQL data base. I want to use the ID of the user and then generate a 5 letters/numbers code like;

```
ID USERNAME   CODE
1  Honf       sdew4
2  Djsoft     hgdTs
3  Hanz       HGSTs
```

Any suggestion of how to make this on php? Thanks!

Comment: If 5 alnums is not a *real* requirement, then you could try an unkeyed hash such as the SHA family.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [base_convert](http://php.net/base_convert) if you want the code to relate to a specific id (this will only use lowercase characters and numbers):

```
$id = 12;
$code = base_convert($id, 10, 36);
//padding to specified length
$code = str_pad($code, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

**rand_uniqid()** function of php may help you.....

```
rand_uniqid(9007199254740989); will return 'PpQXn7COf' and:
rand_uniqid('PpQXn7COf', true); will return '9007199254740989'
```

Comment: Uhh Sorry, But it is in the php.net site http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php......

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hashing algorithm such that

```
substr(strrev(md5($username)),0,5)
```

This will return hex chars. But please note that if you use A-Z, a-z, 0-9 for your hash domain, if you have many users, there may be collisions and those hashes "may not" be unique.